# How to see React Native's console.log on iOS Release mode?

Tags: ios, react-native

So, many times we have some weird things going on in our app.

Development goes alright but on Release mode things go weird.

So, how to see our beloved debugging messages on release mode?

Comment: I'm not a very active SO poster, not sure if this is the way I should share this hint.

Comment: I recommend remove all console.log from your code if you have it. Some times console.log cause issue or like your said "some wierd things".

Answer (score 0):

The way I found to do so is to trick the system thinking any console.log is real error. Follows what I do:

### v0.63 and up

Go to xcode, `CMD + Shift + O`, search for `RCTLog.mm`

Look for the block below:

```
static os_log_type_t RCTLogTypeForLogLevel(RCTLogLevel logLevel)
{
  if (logLevel < RCTLogLevelInfo) {
    return OS_LOG_TYPE_DEBUG;
  } else if (logLevel <= RCTLogLevelWarning) {
    return OS_LOG_TYPE_INFO;
  } else {
    return OS_LOG_TYPE_ERROR;
  }
}
```

and change it to

```
static os_log_type_t RCTLogTypeForLogLevel(RCTLogLevel logLevel)
{
  // if (logLevel < RCTLogLevelInfo) {
  //   return OS_LOG_TYPE_DEBUG;
  // } else if (logLevel <= RCTLogLevelWarning) {
  //   return OS_LOG_TYPE_INFO;
  // } else {
    return OS_LOG_TYPE_ERROR;
  // }
}
```

### v0.62 and below

Go to xcode, `CMD + Shift + O`, search for `RCTLog.mm`

Look for the block below:

```
#if RCT_DEBUG
static const RCTLogLevel RCTDefaultLogThreshold = (RCTLogLevel)(RCTLogLevelInfo - 1);
#else
static const RCTLogLevel RCTDefaultLogThreshold = RCTLogLevelError;
#endif
```

change it to

```
#if RCT_DEBUG
static const RCTLogLevel RCTDefaultLogThreshold = (RCTLogLevel)(RCTLogLevelInfo - 1);
#else
static const RCTLogLevel RCTDefaultLogThreshold = (RCTLogLevel)(RCTLogLevelInfo - 1);
// static const RCTLogLevel RCTDefaultLogThreshold = RCTLogLevelError;
#endif
```

> Just remember to undo that before archiving.

Reinstalling `node_modules` should remove this too.